# Exception in thread "main" - Cannot get class with test cases to run as java application or as debugger

Tags: java, eclipse

I have implemented an AVL tree for my assignment. I imported the TestAVLFrom.java to my project called "Assignment 2". When I try to run the test cases my professor wrote for the class, I am getting this error message:

[image]

When I try to run the test cases through the debugger, I am getting a "Source no found" error:

[image]

I tried googling the problem and read a couple of other posts on stackoverflow regarding this type of error and the consensus was something to do with the classpath. But after reading numerous posts I still couldn't understand what people were talking about.

Here is the code for the test cases:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class TestAVLFrom
{
  public static class Fail extends RuntimeException {
    /**
     * 
     */

    public Fail() { super(); }
    public Fail(String msg) { super(msg); }
  }

  public static interface Test {
    public void test();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test[] suite = {
      new Test0(), new Test1(), new Test2(), new Test3(), new Test4(),
      new Test5(), new Test6(), new Test7(), new Test8(), new Test9(),
      new Test10(), new Test11(), new Test12(), new Test13()
    };

    if (args.length == 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < suite.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("running test " + i);
        suite[i].test(); //Line 30: Error here
      }
      System.out.println("finished");
    } else {
      int count = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < suite.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("test " + i + ": ");
        System.out.flush();
        try {
          suite[i].test();
          System.out.println("pass");
          count++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("fail");
        }
      }
      System.out.println("total: " + count + "/" + suite.length);
    }
  }

  // empty tree
  public static class Test0 implements Test {
    public void test() {
      AVLFrom<String> s = new AVLFrom<String>();
      if (s.find("a")) { throw new Fail(); }
     try { s.from("a", 0); throw new Fail(); } catch (NotFound e) {} //Line 55: Error here
    }
  }
```

EDITED: Removed a lot of code and highlighted ones that gave exceptions in the above picture.

Comment: too much code,can you please limit it and show only the problem part

Comment: Done. I have placed comments on line 55 and line 30.

Comment: Show the code for AVLFrom.from method

Comment: Aren't you throwing that exception yourself at line 55: `throw new Fail();`

Answer (score 1):

Line 55 has a statement that throws `Fail` exception:

```
throw new Fail();
```

Perhaps there is a missing condition, like:

```
if (s.from("a", 0)) 
    throw new Fail();
```

If not, just remove the `throw` as it is always executed and always fails the test. Unless of course there is a `NotFound` exception.